# Using crcmod to generate a checksum in Python

Tags: python-3.x, crc, crc32

I'm trying to get the results I expect from my custom `crcmod` in Python 3.

I currently have the following

```
#                poly,        initCrc,    rev,   xorOut
crc32 = mkCrcFun(0x104c11db7, 0xFFFFFFFF, False, 0xFFFFFFFF)
print(hex(crc32(b'\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f')))
```

This prints `0x94913aa6`. However, I expect to see `0x5395e7dd`, which I calculated [here](http://sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) with the following settings:

- CRC width - CRC-32
- CRC parametrization - Custom
- Input reflected - unchecked
- Result reflected - unchecked
- Polynomial - `0x4c11db7`
- Initial Value - `0xFFFFFFFF`
- Final Xor Value - `0xFFFFFFFF`
- Input - Bytes `0f0f0f0f`

I'm certain that the website is generating the expected checksum. I just can't get `crcmod` to duplicate it for the life of me. Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mkCrcFun(0x104c11db7, 0, False, 0xFFFFFFFF)`.

This is due to the "initial value" having more than one meaning. In the case of `crcmod`, it means the initial register value. In the case of the CRC web page, it means the initial value of the returned CRC. In the latter case, the initial register value is the initial CRC value exclusive-or'ed with the final xor value.